# What is the correct data format when doing a three-way ANOVA test?

Tags: r, statistics

I currently have some data that looks like this:

| person | core | ethnicity | followup | before |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | core | X | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | non-core | Y | 10 | 6 |
| 3 | non-core | Z | 15 | 8 |

I'm trying to look at the affect core and ethnicity have on the before and followup results, however i'm not sure how to put that into one anova in R.

Currently i am using `before ~ core * ethnicity` and `followup ~ core * ethnicity` in seperate tests then looking at them that way with a tukey post-hoc.

However would it be better if my data frame were instead formatted like this:

| person | core | ethnicity | status | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | core | X | before | 0 |
| 1 | core | X | followup | 5 |
| 2 | non-core | Z | before | 10 |
| 2 | non-core | Z | followup | 6 |
| 3 | non-core | Y | before | 15 |
| 3 | non-core | Y | followup | 8 |

with the following ANOVA code `count ~ status * core * ethnicity`?
Thanks

Comment: The before column seems to be changed to after in the expected.  TRy `library(tidyr);library(dplyr);df1 %>% rename(after = before, before = followup) %>% pivot_longer(cols = before:after, names_to = 'status', values_to = 'count')`

Comment: oh true sorry that's my mistake